# Not able to get the request body in the node API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to use Fetch API from a React Client to connect to a Node API, but i am not able to get the payload from the react client in the Node API's Request Body.

**React Client Fetch API -**

```
const fetchAPI = (_URL, _METHOD, _PAYLOAD ) => {

_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/save';
let requestBody = {
    method: _METHOD.toUpperCase(),
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    mode:"no-cors"
}

requestBody["headers"] = {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Cache": "no-cache"
};

_PAYLOAD = {username: 'Test'}

if(_METHOD.toUpperCase() == "POST" ){
     requestBody["body"] = JSON.stringify(_PAYLOAD);
}

return (
        fetch(_URL, requestBody).then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            return(response.json().then((json) => {
                    return json; 
            }
        ))
    }else{
        console.error("Error Response Status - ", response.status);
        console.error("Error Response  - ", response.statusText);
    }
    })

);
```

**Index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 ; 
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
console.log("Request - ", req.body);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Accept");
next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(require('body-parser').json()); 


app.use('/api',router);
```

**router.js:**

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const fs = require('fs');

const router = express.Router();

const fileContent = {'javascript':{"test1":"Test Sample 2", "test2":"Test Sample 3"}};

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.raw());

router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
console.log("Request, Respose - ", req.body);
console.log("Content of a file - ", JSON.stringify(fileContent));
res.status(200).send('Response from server is sent');
fs.writeFile("./sample.txt", JSON.stringify(fileContent), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    };
    console.log("File has been created");
});
})
```

With the above code - When i post the payload to the server api, the request body is logged as an empty object.

```
console.log("Request, Respose - ", req.body); // Request, Respose - {}
```

Comment: could you please press F12, go to the network tab, send an `fetch()` and then inspect if the parameters was sended to the server. Its under Headers then down to request header if post was sended

Comment: Yes i have verified, POST request is made and the payload is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my React Client, I was using mode:'no-cors' and 'Cross-Origin' disabled on my chrome browser. This the reason the payload was not passed over in the request.

I modified my React Client to mode:'cors' with my cors plugin on the chrome browser disabled and now i am able to extract the payload.

React Client -

```
const fetchAPI = (_URL, _METHOD, _PAYLOAD ) => {

_PAYLOAD = {username: 'Test'}
const initObj = {
    method: _METHOD, 
    mode: 'cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    credentials: 'same-origin', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrer: 'no-referrer', 
}


if(_METHOD.toUpperCase() == "POST" ){
    initObj["body"] = JSON.stringify(_PAYLOAD);
}

return (
        fetch(_URL, initObj).then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            return(response.json().then((json) => {
                    return json; 
            }
        ))
    }else{
        console.error("Error Response Status - ", response.status);
        console.error("Error Response  - ", response.statusText);
    }
    })

);
```

}